# Laravel : yt-player isn't displaying

Tags: php, laravel, api, youtube

I'm trying to display a YouTube player with Laravel using the yt-player API : https://www.npmjs.com/package/yt-player

Here is my Laravel show.blade.php Template.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<html>
<head>
<script>
    import * as YTPlayer from 'yt-player';

    this.player = YTPlayer;
    this.player.load('blL9B_dzhoI');
    this.player = new YTPlayer('#player', {
        controls : true,
        related : false,
        info : false,
    });

    this.player.setVolume(100);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col colonne-video"> <div id="player"></div> </div>
   <div class="col colonne-interactive"> some text </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
@endsection
```

I got no error in the Laravel Terminal but one in the Chrome Console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I don't understand this error, and if it is the reason why the YouTube player isn't even displaying on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an import statement directly inside a script tag, as your browser doesn't have access to the npm packages you've installed.

Instead, you need to load the package inside your `resources/js/app.js` (which will be compiled by Laravel Mix).

Add something like this to `app.js`:

```js
window.YTPlayer = require('yt-player')
```

Then, compile the javascript (`yarn dev`), and add the compiled js file to your page (`{{ mix('js/app.js') }}`).

Now you can use the package in your script tag like so:

```js
    var player = new YTPlayer('#player', {
        controls : true,
        related : false,
        info : false,
    });

    player.load('blL9B_dzhoI')
    player.setVolume(100)
```